# Reconciling different definitions of sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

In Bredon's *Sheaf Theory* he defines a sheaf this way

> A Sheaf (of abelian groups) on $X$ is a pair $(\mathscr{A},\pi)$ where:
>
> - $\mathscr{A}$ is a topological space
> - $\pi:\mathscr{A}\to X$ is a local homeomorphism
> - each $\mathscr{A}_x=\pi^{-1}(x)$, for $x\in X$ is an abelian group
> - the group operations are continuous.

(In the sense that the map from $\{(a,b)\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{A}:\pi(a)=\pi(b)\}\to\mathscr{A}$ defined by multiplication is continuous).

However most other sources (like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Sheaves)) I've looked at define a sheaf as a presheaf subject to some extra conditions. Clearly these are different objects. One is a topological space with a map to another and group structures on the fibers, and the other is a contravariant functor. How does one get from one definition to the other, and why did he choose to define a sheaf this way?

Comment: Oh yes: Bredon defines the sheaves (of Abelian groups on a topological space $X$) as the *éspaces étalé* (spread out spaces) of the controvariant functor from $\mathbf{Op}(X)$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_.C3.A9tal.C3.A9_space_of_a_sheaf).